# Cross platform file/disk encryption

Tags: software-recommendation, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to encrypt external hard drive to be readable on any OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18751/how-to-encrypt-external-hard-drive-to-be-readable-on-any-os)

Anyone know any program that works in Ubuntu to encrypt files/disk? I'm looking for something that will ask you for a password to open files when you plug in the pendrive/portable hard disk. If possible, is there any program that can run in both Ubuntu and Windows 7?

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/137828/how-to-encrypt-files-using-a-cross-platform-solution

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt a file using GPG: http://www.linuxdynasty.org/how-to-encrypt-file-using-gpg.html