# How to encrypt folders (not in Home)?

Tags: encryption, directory, partitioning

Is there a way to encrypt a folder, which is not in `Home` (`/home/user/`) but even in a different partition, so only my user can access/read contained files?

Alternatively, I would like to understand if it is possible to turn a complete `ext4` partition into an encrypted volume, which would be mounted at user login.

If possible, I would like to make the change without reinstalling Ubuntu.

My PC has (`mount` output):

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda3 on /home type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sda4 on /home/igor/Personale type ext4 (rw)
```

`sda4` is the partition containing folders I would like to protect.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/137828/how-to-encrypt-files-using-a-cross-platform-solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eCryptfs would be a good choice (Ubuntu encrypted home directory uses ecryptfs) if you want to encrypt /dev/sda4 which is mounted as /home/igor/Personale type ext4

You don't have to re-install anyway. ecryptfs is flexible (you can encrypt folders or partitions) and easy to use, it is layered on top of the current file system - ext4 in your case. Basically you have a partition/block device, create file system and mount it, then use ecryptfs to encrypt it.

In your case, it's /dev/sda4, to encrypt it
NOTE: although this process retains existing data I strongly recommend backing up to a different partition or external HDD. Because later on we need to copy it back to get data encrypted (existing data won't get encrypted).

Steps:

1. install ecryptfs-utils package 1st

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils
   ```
2. mount the destination directory as ecryptfs (suppose /dev/sda4 already mounted on /home/igor/Personale)

   ```
   mount -t ecryptfs /home/igor/Personale /home/igor/Personale
   ```

NOTE: You will be prompted for pass phrase, cipher, key bytes, plaintext passthrough (y/n), filename encryption (y/n).

Done. Existing data won't be encrypted anyway, you can delete existing data and copy if from backup (that's why I recommended backing up, a data swap is needed to activate encryption on existing files). Use rsync for backup/restore:

```
    rsync -axHAX /backup /home/igor/Personale
```

BTW: you can see the encrypted partition use findmnt or mount, e.g
/home/terry/topsecret on /home/terry/topsecret type ecryptfs (rw,ecryptfs_sig=633937dbcf1fef34,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs)

Comment: If I go this way, will I have to manually mount the ecryptfs at every login?

Comment: @igi No, you don't have to manually mount it every time. You can use .ecryptfsrc and set up automatic mount. Check this out https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/ecryptfs.html

Answer (score 6):

Sure. You can use `enfcs`, for example, to create an encrypted folder anywhere. Install encfs with `sudo apt-get install encfs`.

```
mkdir /path/to/encrypted
mkdir /path/do/decrypted
encfs /path/to/encrypted /path/to/decrypted
```

When run on a given encrypted directory for the first time, encfs will take you through setting the password and encryption options.

To unmount the encrypted folder, type

```
fusermount -u /path/to/decrypted
```

To mount the encrypted directory again, type the same command you used to encrypt it:

```
encfs /path/to/encrypted /path/to/decrypted
```

Note that encryption is quite different from Unix permissions ("only my user can access..."). In short, any person and only a person with the credentials (password to the encrypted directory) can decrypt it. That is rather the point of it, because anyone with physical access to your machine can become root, and consequently -- also any user, including you. It is as simple as booting the computer with a live cd or taking out the drive and connecting it to another system.

Comment: Thanks January, so in this case I would need to manually mount folders (or make a script) at every login. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, if you choose that way. No idea how to do it differently.

Comment: I tried using cryptkeeper on top of encfs, but it resulted in errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use LUKS to make an encrypted container which can be used. This has the added effect of being more secure, only the passphrase will open the container. Here is an example:

> #### Create crypto container, loop, and device
>
> - dd if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt/sdcard/loop1.img bs=1M count=128
> - losetup /dev/block/loop1 /mnt/sdcard/loop1.img
> - cryptsetup -c aes-plain luksFormat /dev/block/loop1
> - cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/block/loop1 cpt1
> - mkfs.ext2 /dev/mapper/cpt1
> - mkdir /mnt/sdcard/safe
> - mount /dev/mapper/cpt1 /mnt/sdcard/safe