# Encrypted filesystem shared with Mac OS X

Tags: encryption, macosx, luks

Is there a reliable encrypted filesystem that works under both Mac OS X and Linux?

It need not be the boot partition for either Linux or Mac OS X, but I'd like stable reads and writes if possible.

Comment: There's no "encrypted filesystem" for both, but there's disk encryption and file systems, that work for both.

Comment: linux, windows and mac: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18751/how-to-encrypt-external-devices-using-a-cross-platform-solution related http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92312/can-i-decrypt-a-dm-crypt-filesystem-on-os-x , http://superuser.com/questions/110032/how-to-mount-an-encrypted-ext3-filesystem-under-os-x

Answer (score 3):

TrueCrypt.

There is no good reason not to use it. It works great and if you consider what secret agencies of the US can force people to do, the fact that it is discontinued by its original developer(s) is actually a good thing. There are endeavors to find any kind of security issues and there haven't been found any as of yet.

Comment: There is more here : https://www.grc.com/misc/truecrypt/truecrypt.htm